# Ubuntu 13.04 Runs Very Slow After Update From Xorg-Edgers PPA

Tags: xorg, ppa, performance

Ubuntu Ver - 13-04 32bit.
Kernel Ver - 3.8.0-30-generic
Computer Specs - Pentium IV (2.80GHz × 2) with build in graphics using an Intel 915G.

After getting the latest drivers from Xorg-Edgers PPA the response time and Performance in Unity and Ubuntu altogether is very slow. I need help because this update from Xorg-edgers is key for me to run wine http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34238

Comment: Some times `graphics driver` doesn't match in compatibility with `Kernels`. I've also faced such problem with my `Intel integrated graphics card`. I fixed it by upgrading `Kernel`. Try to install some other latest Kernel.

Comment: how do I go about doing this i recently used this link https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads to get the Intel(R) Linux* Graphics Installer version 1.0.2 and i updated with it but im not sure about the kernal how would i go about updateing the kernal?

Comment: What are those "compatibility reasons" you are talking about? Did the perfomance was OK while you were using the default drivers? What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A6 VGA`? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please, **edit your question, and add the details**.

Comment: my ubuntu version is on the title 13.04 I need this update to run wine http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34238 lspci -nnk | grep -A6 VGA I have no idea what your talking about im a noob I wouldnt be using ubuntu if my windows xp didnt crash on me

Comment: no this is not a duplicate of that problem nothing is broke its the Performance the performance after the update makes everything super slow it takes a full 30 sec if not a full 2 minutes for the launchbar on Unity to load and right clicking an icon on the desktop takes about 26sec to load the menu. I dont think its the kernel im using the 3.8.0-30-generic. and Xorg-edgers says 3.6.0 of higher is required.